# How to fix the "Role doesn't exist" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku-postgres

I just created a new Ruby on rails project using this, in order to deploy it with Heroku

```
rails new -d postgresql LG_1
```

Then I used rails s to run my server and found this error :

```
role "esteban" does not exist.
```

I've been looking for solutions for an hour, but none of them worked. Using createuser just gives me the does-not-exist error, and I'm not very comfortable with Rails.

The versions I'm using :

```
Ruby 2.4.4
Rails 5.2.3
Pg (gem) 1.1.4
```

Here is my database.yml file (without the 75 lines of comments) :

```
default: &default
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    host: /var/run/postgresql
    pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
    <<: *default
    database: LG_1_development

test:
     <<: *default
     database: LG_1_test

production:
    <<: *default
    database: LG_1_production
    username: LG_1
    password: <%= ENV['LG_1_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

I did not edit this file.

EDIT : I found the solution. I had to open the pg_hba.conf file and manually add a new user called "esteban"

Comment: can you add what you have written on database.yml

Answer (score 0):

Did you install new Gem for project?

If you did I think what you didn't database migration.

Please run following commands.

```
$heroku run rake db:migrate

$heroku ps:scale web=1

$heroku ps

$heroku open
```

Comment: Can't use heroku at the moment because of the error

Comment: Can I check your source? If you can please github address or something.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `esteban` is the user name on your local machine and because you dont set specific username and password in `database.yml` for `development` mode postgres uses username of your user when trying to open connection to database.

Create role `esteban` in postgres:

```
# go to psql console under default postgres user
psql postgres 
# create role
create role esteban SUPERUSER LOGIN;
# exit psql
\q
```

Or set correct one in `database.yml` if you already have it

Comment: When I do use "psql postgres", I have an error "role esteban does not exist"